# Dynamic schedule of cron job in aws serverless

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless-framework, serverless

Is it possible to schedule event(cron job) dynamically from lambda function instead from the fixed rate mentioned in YML file? If so please provide example

Comment: Please define what you mean with "dynamically".

Comment: it means to start and stop cloudwatch cronjob from a lambda function depending upon certain conditions.

Comment: Use the [PutRule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/APIReference/API_PutRule.html) API from your Lambda. Remember to set permissions to allow Lambda to call `events:PutRule`.